# Call JSP from servlet

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

Error ->

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
> type Status report

> message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

> description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

**web.xml**

```xml
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   version="3.0">

   <display-name>To do List</display-name>

   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**LoginServlet.java**

```java
package com.todo;

//imports ->
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

// url ->
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login.do")

// response genrator ->
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {{
        // JSP code response ->
       
        RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/veiws/login.jsp");
        RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);   }
}
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>hello world from jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello world from jsp! 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code blocks are good. But try to add what you tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create a method doGet(...) for a GET request.
If both GET and POST do the same things, you can create another method and call it from doPost and doGet.

Have a nice day